# Corrispondente, corrisposto, corrispondendo

Tags: grammar, difference

I would like to ask, what is the difference of the two "participio" and "gerundio"?

Here is an example in the text book:

> Quando trovate qualcuno, scrivete il suo nome nella casella corrispondente all'attività svolta.

Is "corrispondente all'attività svolta" used to describe the word "casella"?

- Write his name in the square which corresponds to the activity.

Or it is related with the action of "scrivete il suo nome"?

- Write his name in the square, corresponding to the activity.

Does it make sense if I use another participio "corrisposto" or the gerundio "corrispondendo"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Corrispondente" is the "participio presente" of "corrispondere", but is also an [adjective](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/corrispondente/) that means "che corrisponde", i.e., *which corresponds*. As an adjetive, if you write it after a noun, it qualifies such noun. So, in this case, it refers to the noun "casella".

Answer (score 2):

The meaning here of the *participio presente* is exactly the one you rephrase as “which corresponds to”.

The *participio passato* is either used for the composite forms of the verbs (*le risposte non hanno corrisposto alle domande*) or is used as an adjective denoting something that has done or received the action of the verb. *Corrisposto* would refer to something that corresponded to something (admittedly, *corrispondere* is not an especially versatile verb to make examples).

Finally, the *gerundio* is mostly used together with an auxiliary verb to express a continuous action, analogously to English: *sto andando* is “I'm going”, with just some different nuances. It can be used by itself, but its use doesn't correspond exactly to English one. You would not say, in that sentence, *scrivete il suo nome corrispondendo a...*. If anything, such a *gerundio* would have as its subject the same as the main phrase (the person who writes), so you could for instance say *scrivete il suo nome usando una matita*.

Comment: Besides “complemento di tempo*, *gerundio* also expresses *causa*, *modo*, *mezzo*.